# Custom border of uitextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I need make login form like Facebook app (http://pttrns.com/logins#/detail/cf098fbe9dc609472c0c80d257db7ee2). I didn't find default decision. I suppose that i must make something with border of `UITextField`.
Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I think the form was done using a UITableView using grouped style with UITextfields in it.

Comment: A little off the topic but why is this poor souls question marked with -2? What did he ask that was so wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `borderStyle` of your text view to `UITextBorderStyleNone` and then you can place them on top of whatever you want. In Facebook's case, it looks like they're on top of a table view, but you could put any image behind them.